# Retrieve jquery post in php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been searching for hours for this and still cant seem to find the solution. I am trying to use jquery to send a javascript variable to a php form

in one file.. index.php I have the following line:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

in test.php, I have

```
$h = $_POST['name'];
print $h;
```

but nothing is printed. Sorry if this is a repetitive question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: @tymeJV nothing is printed.

Comment: your javascript console has nothing to do with php print @user1011332

Comment: Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'Abstract' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'Abstract' of null
    at chrome-extension://mmffncokckfccddfenhkhnllmlobdahm/scripts/popup_bubble.js:337:38
    at chrome-extension://mmffncokckfccddfenhkhnllmlobdahm/scripts/env_setup.js:97:13
    at miscellaneous_bindings:287:9
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage

Answer (score 5):

You aren't doing anything with the data that is being returned by the server, you need to access the `callback` and use the data that is being printed.

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data){
    //data is what you send back from the server, in this scenario, the $h variable.
    alert(data); 
});
```

Comment: My main goal is transfer those js variables to php... It still isn't working.

Comment: When you say "It isn't working", what do you mean? How do you know it is not transferring the JS variables to PHP? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm such a noob. I mean I am just trying to access the JS variables through php and whatever I do.. doesnt seem to work (including the snippet you posted above)

Comment: @user1011332 Then the issue is with A) Location of the file, B) Not wrapping this code in `$(document.ready(function(){ //your code });`, or C) not including jQuery in your page. Check your Console, within your Web Developer tools (if you don't know how to find that, google that phrase along with your browser's name), and see if it succeeds, or if there's an error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not being told where to display the data. You have to tell it what to do when it receives a successful HTTP response,

`$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`

Your code should actually be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
 // You can change .content to any element you want your response to be printed to.
 $('.content').html(data);
});
</script>
```